# Appending multi-indexed Series to an empty Series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, append, series

I take a multi-indexed pandas series named 'dat' and try to append it to an empty series named 's'. This is how 'dat' looks like:

```
a = [['bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],['one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
t = list(zip(*a))
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(t, names=['first', 'second'])
dat = pd.Series(randn(4), index=ind)

Out[1]: 
first  second
bar    one      -1.361606
       two      -0.108458
foo    one      -0.691175
       two      -0.830161
dtype: float64
```

Now, when I append it to the empty Series 's' it returns this:

```
s = pd.Series()
s = s.append(dat)
Out[2]: 
(bar, one)   -1.361606
(bar, two)   -0.108458
(foo, one)   -0.691175
(foo, two)   -0.830161
dtype: float64
```

How can I recover the original form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug fixed in 0.14.0 (coming next week), see here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0140-api (the set_index section).

You can get the pre-release here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/releases

Comment: Great! It works now... I was almost going crazy for this. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff This bug seems to have been re-introduced in 18.1.  Do you know the original issue report?

Comment: you would have to show an example; we have this specific test

Comment: The code from the question creates a single-level index in 18.1, but keeps the multi-level index in 18.0.